# What is this treasure in Lara’s trophy collection?

Tags: tomb-raider-iii

In the Croft Manor section of *Tomb Raider 3*, there is a hidden trophy room containing relics from Lara’s previous adventures. Most of these are references to previous games - fragments of the Scion of Atlantis from the first game, the Dagger of Xian from *Tomb Raider 2*, the eponymous Golden Mask from *TR2*’s expansion pack, and a T. rex head on the wall. Then there’s this.

[image: Lara looks at a weird unidentified treasure]

(The image is taken from the recent remastered collection, but it looks much the same in the original). A red ball, surrounded by three hemispheres, all magically floating and rotating. Is this also an item from a previous game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like **Iris** from the first meeting of Werner Von Croy and Lara Croft in Angkor Wat, Cambodia in **Tomb Raider: The Last Revelation**. You can find more information at the [wiki here](https://tombraider.fandom.com/wiki/Iris).

Comment: Yeah, that’s it. It didn’t occur to me that it might be from a flashback in a future game.